# How to define the JS file which contains the method to be executed in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am working with an example of a project that I found out in internet and I am trying to know how to call a simple `onclick` method from one `button`. What I have tried is to declare it as:

**HTML**

```
        <button id="bt_connect" src="./js/example.js" onclick="mqtt_sub();">MQTT CONNECTION</button>
```

to call a `function` which I have defined in `./js/example.js`

```
function mqtt_sub() {
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var client = mqtt.connect("url:1883"); // URL:port
var topic = 'testingtopic'

client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
    message = message.toString();
    console.log(message);
});

client.on('connect', () => {
    client.subscribe(topic);
    console.log("Connected!")
})

}
```

**ERROR**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: mqtt_sub is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

I know that I could define the script in the `HTML` file, but I can not execute `require()`

What I would like to know is if my code is wrong, or it is supposed to be like this. I would like to double check it to know if I need to look into my code or I just misunderstood the structure of my project.

Comment: If you want to use require you must also include require.js in your script tag. So, there will be two script tags in your html

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.js"> </script>
<script src= "your_script.js"> </script>

By adding require.js library you will find require.

Comment: It looks like the script you want to execute is a server-side script ..?

Comment: @Charu — The require library isn't going to do a lot of good unless the script being required is designed to run in a browser in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A button element does not have a src attribute.
If you want to call an onclick method from your button you need to call the function defined in your JS file itself.

To make it recognize this method, you can add the JS file inside a script tag before the closing body tag.

```
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
   ....
  <script src="your_src"></script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I was actually updating my question while you were replying it. As I have mentioned, I can not use this solution cause require() can not be used on the client side.

Comment: @Mario - you don't have to use require for this.

Comment: @Mario — Well, trying to load the script through a mechanism you invented and which browsers don't support isn't going to add support for `require` as a side effect. Focus your question on a single problem. This answer solves your primary problem. You could ask a different question about supporting `require` (although do *search* first, there are lots of questions about using `require` or trying to use code designed for Node.js in a browser).